# How to match the table and schema name from database?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

The name of my table in the database is abc.Company where abc is a schema. How can I create the model class so that the name matches my table name in the database? I have done as depicted below but it's not able to return any record from the database. The controller gives 0 records from the database.

Any ideas?

CompanyController.cs

```
public ActionResult CompanyDetails()
{
    IList<AddCompanyViewModel> viewModels = new List<AddCompanyViewModel>();

    var companies = db.Companies.ToList<Company>();

    foreach (var company in companies)
    {
         viewModels.Add(new AddCompanyViewModel
         {
             CompanyId=company.CompanyId,
             CompanyCode = company.CompanyCode,
             CompanyName = company.CompanyName,
             IsCompanyActive = company.Active,
             CreatedOn = company.CreatedDate
         });
    }

    return View(viewModels);
}
```

Entity Model Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MiJack.Web.ProjectAdmin.Entities
{
       
    public class Company
    {
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
       public int CompanyId { get; set; }
       public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
       public string CompanyName { get; set; }
       public bool Active { get; set; }
       public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DataAccessLayer Class:

```
using MiJack.Web.ProjectAdmin.Entities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace MiJack.Web.ProjectAdmin.DataAccessLayer
{
   public class ProjectAdminDAL:DbContext
   {
      public ProjectAdminDAL() : base("ProjectAdmin")
      {
  
      }
        private static IDictionary<string, string> entitySetNames { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

        
        static ProjectAdminDAL()
        {
            // A dictionary that stores a mapping between entity objects (e.g. Vehicle) and
            // DbSets (e.g. Vehicles).
            //
            // This allows us to have a single Add method in Repository.cs that adds entities
            // to the object context by the DbSet name
            // Format
            //
            // { Entity, DbSet }
            // e.g.
            // { "Lock", "Locks" }
            ProjectAdminDAL.entitySetNames = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                {"Company", "Companies"},
            };

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MiJack.Web.ProjectAdmin.ViewModels.AddCompanyViewModel> 
        AddCompanyViewModels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute?view=netcore-3.1) attribute to define the targeted schema:

```
[Table("Company", Schema = "abc"]
public class Company
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I already tried that but it gives me this error. "'The model backing the 'ProjectAdminDAL' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).'"

Comment: Are you doing code first databasses? If so: did you alter the schema in the database? If so, rollback you manual change, add the attribute and create a migration and update the database. Basically the error says the defined database does not match the last known state - and it throws an error.

Comment: I didn't alter the schema in the database. What I did is added the table attribute as suggested by you and added  Database.SetInitializer<ProjectAdminDAL>(null); in global.asax.cs in Application_Start() method and it worked!